# Kusto Query for aggregated Graphs in Dashboards (ADX)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am creating dashboards in Azure data explorer (ADX) with Kusto Query Language. In ADX I have an option to create multiple charts within a single Dashboard by using Add tile option. But I would like to know is there a way to use one Query to create aggregated charts (skip the Add tile option).

for example - I have a table that has Virtual machine OS , status, size, cost . In a single Dashboard I need to have 2 seperate graphs. 1) Status of diff VM with OS, 2) Size and cost of VM in second graph. So I need to aggregate the graphs within dashboard. I am not sure how to seperate 2 Queries in same Dashboard. I did search and did not find any results.Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This capability does not exist today but it is high on the list of future improvements. Feel free to add a suggestion though in the [Azure data explorer user voice](https://aka.ms/kustouservoice)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will add the suggestion. Do I have this option in Power BI ? May be use Kusto Query to PowerBI for aggregated charts .

Comment: Yes, powerbi brings the data to its own model and you can create as many visuals as you want from the same table.